# Comparing The android action bar compat, pager and tabs sample to ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I hope this question will not be rejected as there is no code. But still, I think it could interest some people as android documentation of action bar and its compatibility is becoming quite large these times.

I have an app I would like to convert to a new UI using action bar, tabs and pager.
But I want it to be compatible from android 4.0 down to android 2.2 let's say.

What are the possibilities, advantages and drawbacks of using either :

- action bar from ICS with support api + some code from samples (like [actionbar compat](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html) & [support samples for tabs and pager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html))
- versus action sherlock [tabs+pager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java) ?
- versus action sherlock [action bar tabs](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/TabNavigation.java) ?

Thanks !

Comment: I tryed actionbarsherlock and was impressed at first but had too many problems with the ADT so ended up switching to ationbar compat.

Comment: Thx for answering that the kind of feedback I am looking for.

Comment: @Warpzit, What problems did you have with the ADT?

Comment: @Kevin I had problem with ADT detection the R files etc. this issue has probrably been fixed since then but was making it unworkable for me. Another advantage with actionbar compat is that you are mostly in control while with actionbarsherlock you are dependent on a third party. Of course this could also be seen as a disdavantage ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used ABS on several projects and it's a dream. It saves me an enormous amount of time, the apps look great, and the version compatibility is excellent.

Navigation Tabs are a Google recommended approach to primary navigation as part of the ActionBar, so I'd say use that (or ActionBar actions, or a drop-down spinner), unless you have a good reason not too. And as it's in ABS and works back to older versions, it's pretty easy to implement, so you can spend time on the actual app.

ABS does take a little effort to get the dependencies set up, but it's just a library project, it's not hard, and the little time needed is massively made up for by the benefits.

I think the main difference between the last two options is whether you want users to side-swipe between tabs, and that will depend on the app. If you want side-swiping, go with the pager, if not the ActionBar NavigationTabs will probably do the job.

Comment: I give some more time for others, but your answer is great.

Comment: I installed eclipse 3.2, maven, m2e + android connector, allowed some workspace resolution for maven and with ABS, my project with tabs and action bar works. Just some happy coding time in view. Thx for your feedback.