# Android: Setup App with ActionBar, Tabs, Fragments, Swipe compatible with SDK 8 (Android 2.2)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm planning an Android app that should make use of lots of UI features that later SDK versions bring with them incl. ActionBar, ActionBar.Tabs, Swipe navigation and use of Fragments (with replace, add, FragmentTransaction etc). The app should support SDK 8 (2.2) and later.

I'm a 'bit' at a loss here on how to set this up: will I be able to use all these features with the official Android compatibility library? Or will I have to use ActionBarSherlock? Will ABS give me advantages/ be easier to implement compared to the official comp. library?

Can I use the Eclipse/ ADT navigation templates with those two librarys? Can I use them alongside each other or do I have to comit to one of them?

Lot's of questions, I know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will I be able to use all these features with the official Android compatibility library?

No.

> Or will I have to use ActionBarSherlock?

Yes.

> Will ABS give me advantages/ be easier to implement compared to the official comp. library?

It will give you a backwards-compatible action bar. The Android Support Library does not.

> Can I use the Eclipse/ ADT navigation templates with those two librarys?

You can do whatever you want. You will need to replace some stuff generated by those templates.

Answer (score 0):

I think using using ActionBarSherlock is the best.
Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104625/comparing-the-android-action-bar-compat-pager-and-tabs-sample-to-actionbarsherl)